# Coin flip game save issue

Tags: java

I am creating a coin flip game for an assignment that saves your last high score and name. the program works fine if there is not a high score file already there, but if there is a file there the program stops working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class BradySkuza43
{

public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String coin, again, bestName, saveFile = "coin-flip-score.txt";
    int flip, streak = 0, best;

    File in = new File(saveFile);
    if ( in.createNewFile() )
    {
        System.out.println("Save game file doesn't exist. Created.");
        best = 1;
        bestName = " ";
    }
    else
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
        bestName = input.next();
        best = input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        System.out.println("High score is " + best + " flips in a row by " + bestName );
    }

    do
    {
        flip = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*2);

        if ( flip == 1 )
        {
        coin = "HEADS";
        }
        else
        {
        coin = "TAILS";
        }

        System.out.println( "You flip a coin and it is... " + coin );

        if ( flip == 1 )
        {
            streak++;
            System.out.println( "\tThat's " + streak + " in a row...." );
            System.out.print( "\tWould you like to flip again (y/n)? " );
            again = keyboard.next();
        }
        else
        {
            streak = 0;
            again = "n";
        }
    } while ( again.equals("y") );

    System.out.println( "Final score: " + streak );

    if ( streak > best )
    {
        System.out.println("That's a new high score!");
        System.out.print("Your name: ");
        bestName = keyboard.next();
        best = streak;
    }
    else if ( streak == best )
    {
        System.out.println("That ties the high score. Cool.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("You'll have to do better than " + streak + "if you want a high score.");
    }


    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter(saveFile) );
    out.println(bestName);
    out.println(best);
    out.close();
}
}
```

when there is a file already there I get a NoSuchElement error. I am assuming it has to do with the import functions but I am unaware of how to fix it.

Comment: It's because you create a file, which may end up empty (if you don't get a high score) and then you try to read from that empty file.  You shouldn't create the high score file unless you are _actually_ going to write to it.  Or you should handle an empty high score file.

Answer (score 1):

The way you read 'best' when there is already a file (with the 'best' value) seems to be incorrect. You may be looking for something like this (modify based on your data) to read the 'saved best value'.

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in));

        String readNumber = "";
        while (reader.readLine() != null) {
            readNumber += reader.readLine();
        }
        best = Integer.valueOf(readNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended up having to just run the code to see how the savefile is being produced. Seeing that NoSuchElement exception is coming from the second read from the file (input.nextInt()) pointed to the problem.

If you don't beat the existing the streak (including getting TAILS as your first flip), you aren't prompted for a name. This makes the savefile read

```
\n
1
\n
```

Scanner by default ignore whitespace. You don't check if there is available input (hasNext methods). When you call the next() or nextInt() when there is no input you get NoSuchElement. Why is this happening from the save?

Line by line:

```
bestName = input.next();   <-- This is getting the "1" since there is a name saved
best = input.nextInt();    <-- since the 1 was already read, so there's nothing to get
```

That second input with the savefile after getting an initial TAILS, is causing your crash.

Two solutions, make sure you are getting and saving the bestName in the else at the end of your main, or be more careful in reading the savefile.

**(edit)**
In general when using Scanner (or just about anything API that has a the hasNext()/next() style), it's best to call and check hasNext() before each next(). This will ensure you have something to get from the next().

Even if you don't think there is a possible reason for there not to be something there, having something like

```
if(!foo.hasNext) { 
    System.out.println("foo should really have something here, but hasNext says it doesn't);
    System.exit();
}
```

will stop your code in its tracks if there is a problem, and give you a stop to add some debug statements to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Your high score file's name doesn't change, right?  It shouldn't be a variable, it should be a `static final` variable.
2. Play the game and *then* decide whether or not this is a high score.  So you should have a `getHighScore()` method (which can be `static`).
3. If the *new* score is a high score, then write it to the high score file.  There should be a method `static writeHighScore(final String name, final int score)`.

So I would change your program to something more like this:

```
public class BradySkuza43
{
    public static final String HIGH_SCORE_FILE = "coin-flip-score.txt";

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int highScore = getHighScore();
        final int newScore = getScore(keyboard);

        if(newScore != 0 && newScore > highScore){
            final String name = getName(keyboard);
            writeHighScore(name, newScore);
    }

    private static int highScore(){
        // read high score from high score file or return Integer.MIN_VALUE if 
        //    no high score file exists
    }

    private static int getScore(final Scanner keyboard){
        // play game, prompt user, get input, etc. and then 
        //   return the player's score.
    }

    private static String getName(final Scanner keyboard){
        // prompt the user for their name and return their input
    }

    private static void writeHighScore(final String name, final int score){
        // write this high score (with the name) to the high score file
    }

}
```